# モデルのindexをネストしたjsonで返す方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

controllerで下記のようにindexを返している部分を変更して、Modelの要素の:item_idでグループ化してitem_idごとにネストした状態で返したいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？

```
models = Model.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => models }
end
```

Comment: 「:item_idでグループ化してitem_idごとにネストした状態」ではどうなって欲しいのか通じませんので、期待する出力を具体的に書いた方がよいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
format.json { render :json => models.group_by(&:item_id) }
```

でどうでしょうか？